# No text message notifications at all

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms, notifications, lumia-950

Some time ago my phone stopped giving any notifications when I receive text messages. Given the nature of the problem I have no idea when exactly this happened, as I just thought that I wasn't getting any texts.

I have a dual sim Lumia 950 with a T-Mobile sim. This isn't about just the noise/vibration. There is no change in the live tile, and texts aren't showing up in the notification pull down screen, nor on my computer through Cortana. I've restarted the phone multiple times and the problem persists, so I'm stumped.

[image: I do have the notification settings on]

Comment: Same problem was occurred to me, if I open messages app then only messages will display/ show notifications. Just do a soft reset

Comment: Soft reset? I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: I did try this. No dice: still have the same problem.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you recieve a text while the phone is put on charge?

Comment: Yup. There's just no notification whatsoever. Other messaging apps, WhatsApp, skype, etc still make sounds and notifications

Comment: Hmmmm.......Seems like you're not getting messages via Messaging app. Have you changed your default messaging app to some other app (e.g.Skype)? It may lead to this problem. Try setting default messaging app to Microsoft Messaging.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your messaging app is allowed to run in the background. If it is not, it won't be able to send notifications, etc. In the settings menu for allowing/disabling background apps the messaging app has the name "Microsoft Messaging" as well as a winking smiley face message bubble which is low resolution a not similar in any way to the standard messaging tile. Don't be confused, as they are in fact one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Skype ,soft reset -google for it if unknown- reinstall Skype  without enabling its sms or msg notification.
To me worked like this,out of thousands try ;)

Comment: Uninstalled skype, reset phone yet the problem persists. I did try setting skype as the primary messaging app, which seems to work fine. I'll just use that in the future.

Comment: For me, notifications started working again when I selected Microsoft Messaging as the primary messaging app. For some reason it was set to Skype, although I don't know how long it's been like that.